# feign.RetryableException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message executing GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions

Tags: azure, ssl

I get the following error while Azure API calls when retrieving Azure resources. Any Idea why?

feign.RetryableException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message executing GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks?api-version=2020-06-30

Answer (score 0):

The error message is related to a virtual disk and could be in a faulty state. I would go through your [disks on the portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Compute%2Fdisks) and see if any of them show in a faulty state. Another alternative is to use `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks?api-version=2020-06-30` by your resource groups and determine which disk(s) reports the same error.

Regards,
Ryan